# Static Salt In Argon2 For Converting ECDH Shared Secret Into AES Key

Tags: salt, argon2

I am using Argon2 to convert an ECDH exchange result into the correct format for AES-256 encryption. However the library that I am using for Argon2 requires a salt. Are there any weaknesses of using a static, hard-coded salt for the Argon2 key format conversion?

Comment: Related [Key derivation functions (KDF): What are? Main purposes? How can they be used?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/40757/18298)

Comment: Would rainbow tables be constructed for SECP521r1 shared secrets?? If so, what would the salt length recommendation be?

Comment: a shared secret does not need a high work factor KDF to get you a cipher key, you can use a single iteration of a 256-bit hash, or use a 512-bit hash such as SHA-512 if you need additional key material, such as an HMAC key